# Using SqlTransaction in C#, how to get an output parameter from a stored procedure and insert into another table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have two tables: Table1 and Table2. I need newly inserted Id (from `Table1`) as an output parameter which should be inserted into `Table2`. And I must use `SqlTransaction` or `TransactionScope` here.

Stored procedure:

```
    CREATE PROC InsertTable1
    (
        @Name nvarchar(50),
        @OutputParam int out
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Table1(Name) 
        VALUES(@Name)

        SELECT @OutputParam = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
    END
```

C# code:

```
SqlTransaction transaction = db.sqlconn.BeginTransaction();

SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Name", "TestName");
param[1] = new SqlParameter("@OutputParam", SqlDbType.Int);
param[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(transaction, "InsertTable1", param);

int outputId = (int)param[1].Value;
```

When I run and debug the project I get an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

just after execution of

```
int outputId = (int)param[1].Value;
```

I think the transaction is closing the connection or something. It works if I don't use transaction. But I have to use transaction anyhow. I am open to any alternative ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: What is "SqlHelper"? That may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the overload of [`SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery`](http://www.agilechai.com/source/SqlHelper-Source-Code-cs.html) you are using takes an array of parameter **values**, not an array of `SqlParameter`. It only compiles and runs because the type is `object`. So it will derive its own parameters via a `SqlCommandBuilder` and try to set the values on them from your param argument, but of course a SqlParameter cannot have a SqlParameter as its `.Value`. 
The point is moot however, because the comments on the source code (below) specifically say you have no access to OUTPUT or RETURN values from this method.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a stored procedure via a SqlCommand (that returns no resultset) against the specified 
    /// SqlTransaction using the provided parameter values.  This method will query the database to discover the parameters for the 
    /// stored procedure (the first time each stored procedure is called), and assign the values based on parameter order.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method provides no access to output parameters or the stored procedure's return value parameter.
    /// 
    /// e.g.:  
    ///  int result = ExecuteNonQuery(conn, trans, "PublishOrders", 24, 36);
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="transaction">a valid SqlTransaction</param>
    /// <param name="spName">the name of the stored procedure</param>
    /// <param name="parameterValues">an array of objects to be assigned as the input values of the stored procedure</param>
    /// <returns>an int representing the number of rows affected by the command</returns>
    public static int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlTransaction transaction, string spName, params object[] parameterValues)
    {
        //if we receive parameter values, we need to figure out where they go
        if ((parameterValues != null) && (parameterValues.Length > 0))
        {
            //pull the parameters for this stored procedure from the parameter cache (or discover them & populate the cache)
            SqlParameter[] commandParameters = SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(transaction.Connection.ConnectionString, spName);

            //assign the provided values to these parameters based on parameter order
            AssignParameterValues(commandParameters, parameterValues);

            //call the overload that takes an array of SqlParameters
            return ExecuteNonQuery(transaction, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName, commandParameters);
        }
        //otherwise we can just call the SP without params
        else
        {
            return ExecuteNonQuery(transaction, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Though I've already solved this issue using TransactionScope, your clear explanation has helped me to understand the mistake I did. I've tried another overload of SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery and it works as expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ChanchalZoarder Thanks for the heads up. using TransactionScope seems to be easiest solution to using output params with transactions.

Answer (score 1):

For problems concerning transactions take a look TransactionScope class. Here is the intro part from microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818746%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> The TransactionScope class provides a simple way to mark a block of
>   code as participating in a transaction, without requiring you to
>   interact with the transaction itself. A transaction scope can select
>   and manage the ambient transaction automatically. Due to its ease of
>   use and efficiency, it is recommended that you use the
>   TransactionScope class when developing a transaction application.

Also you have transaction properties ([TransactionInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.transactioninformation.aspx) and [Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.current.aspx)) at your disposal to investigate status of transaction while debugging. This is all I can think of right now that wasn't suggested already.

Answer (score 0):

USE `OUTPUT` clause to get inserted data and save into a temporary table.

Return that data from stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the value in output, if you want to insert data in another table, inside the stored procedure you can easily write another insert query which inserts this id in another table

Comment: I have to do some other calculations with the received output parameter in C# and then it is to be inserted through another stored procedure. So I need the output parameter in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using Customize SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery method for executing query, could you please share SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery method

Comment: SqlHelper class is from Microsoft Data Access Application Block and designed by Microsoft itself. I tried typical SqlCommand too. But getting the same error.